# Extract ids from input

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have input like

```
"ABC""XYZ""WER"
```

I want output like

```
ABC,XYZ,WER
```

What I did

```
 tr -d '"'
```

This removes all the character ", I want to replace "" with , and remove single ". 
Input is a output of grep command and i am adding pipe to output of grep.

```
grep something. | sed -e 's/""//g'
```

It's giving me error sed: no input files

If if write someThing like

```
sed -i 's/""/g' file.txt
```

I get char 6: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Don't use parameters blindly. Remove the i parameter for sed.

Comment: yeah, got that. since it's a stream inline editing not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use following `sed` command to do that,

```
sed 's/""/,/g;s/"//g' <<<'"ABC""XYZ""WER"'
```

Two steps for `sed`:

1. substitute each `""` with `,` in the stream
2. after step 1, eliminate single `"` in the stream

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Please explain it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Got it

Comment: At the end `sed` looks like the right tool for this job. +1

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/""/,",");gsub(/"/,"")}1' file
```

`gsub` is used for regex search and replace. The first one replaces `""` by a `,` the second one replaces the `"` at the start and end of the line. `1` makes `awk` print the line.

---

With `gawk`:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^\"]+";OFS=","}{$1=$1}1' file
```

The command is `gawk` specific because I use the `FPAT` special variable. It describes how a *field* in the input looks like. A field in your input is a sequence of non double-quote characters.

`OFS` is the *output field delimiter* which we wanna set to `,`.

`$1=$1` is just an identity transformation but it makes `awk` re-render the line using the new output delimiter `,`.

`1` is always true and makes awk finally print the line.

Answer (score 2):

if you have `grep` which supports `-o` option

> -o, --only-matching
>
> Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output
>                 line.

```
$ echo '"ABC""XYZ""WER"' | grep -o '[^"]*'
ABC
XYZ
WER

$ echo '"ABC""XYZ""WER"' | grep -o '[^"]*' | paste -sd,
ABC,XYZ,WER
```

or with `perl`

```
$ echo '"ABC""XYZ""WER"' | perl -lne 'print join ",", /[^"]+/g'
ABC,XYZ,WER
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU **awk**:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
       printf "%s%s",substr($i,2,length($i)-2),(i==NF? ORS:",") }' <<<'"ABC""XYZ""WER"'
```

The output:

```
ABC,XYZ,WER
```

Answer (score 0):

With portable awk you can replace the field separator like this:

```
awk '$1=$1' FS='""' OFS=,
```

Which will replace `""` with `,`. The `$1=$1` bit forces awk to do field and record splitting.

So to answer your question, you could do something like this:

```
<<<'"ABC""XYZ""WER"'\
awk '$1=$1' FS='""' OFS=, | tr -d \"
```

Output:

```
ABC,XYZ,WER
```

Answer (score 0):

With cut

```
echo '"ABC""XYZ""WER"' | cut -d '"' -f 2,4,6 --output-delimiter=','
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/"([^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*)"/\1,/g;s/,$//' file
```

This replaces strings enclosed in double quotes (including quoted characters that may be double quoted) and replaces them by the string only followed by a comma. The final comma is then removed.